# How to check if my cross compiled executable is dynamic or static?

Tags: linux, build, mips, cross-compiling

I used crosstools-ng to compile shadowsocks for my router, on my router, I can just `ldd myExecutable` to list the dependencies,

```
$ ssh root@my-router-ip
root@unknown:/tmp/home/root# ldd ./ss-server 
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x2aabf000)
        libm.so.0 => /lib/libm.so.0 (0x2ac23000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x2ac37000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x2ac56000)
        libc.so.0 => /lib/libc.so.0 (0x2ac78000)
        libdl.so.0 => /lib/libdl.so.0 (0x2accb000)
        ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x2aaa8000)
```

but right now I don't have my router with me, how do I check it?
tried with the tools from crosstools-ng compiled toolchain which used to compile the executable

```
$ mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ldd /home/oglop/Downloads/ss-install/bin/ss-server
mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ldd: no root given
Try `mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ldd --help' for more information


$ mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-readelf -d /home/oglop/Downloads/ss-install/bin/ss-server

There is no dynamic section in this file.
```

I have already tried methods here in [How to list library dependencies of a non-native binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052041/how-to-list-library-dependencies-of-a-non-native-binary), none of them works.