# error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: internal error

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

**TLDR:**
**Running a program on arm (cross-compiled on Ubuntu) which uses openCV generates error: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: internal error**

I posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319909/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-internal-error) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/108659/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libopencv_highguiso31-internal-error/) but I've got no luck so I'm trying here.

I cross-compiled OpenCV for arm following [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html), and built [this sample program](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage) using `cmake` and `make`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

(host: Ubuntu, target: arm)

When I copy the binary and the libs to the target and run the binary I get this error:

> ./DisplayImage: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: internal error

This is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ )
```

---

**edit 2: I forgot to mention the following also in CMakeLists.txt:**

```
SET( GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.3")
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

Without these 2 lines I get `-sh: ./DisplayImage: not found`. So I add them to tell the program where to find the linker. It works with other programs that don't use OpenCV...

---

This is not a duplicate of "[openCV program compile error “libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” in ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335848/opencv-program-compile-error-libopencv-core-so-2-4-cannot-open-shared-object-f)" because I'm not getting a "No such file or directory..."

Why am I getting this or how can I get more information about the error?
I tried running `strace` on the program and I got:

```
open("/home/my_host_user/opencv/opencv/platforms/linux/my_build_dir/lib/vfp/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/my_host_user/opencv/opencv/platforms/linux/my_build_dir/lib/vfp", 0x7e9e94f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

... //and more like these
```

So it's like something is still linked with the host machine names (see *my_host_user* and *my_build_dir* - these are directories in my host machine)

**edit 1:**
**I also get this error with `strace`:**

```
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**edit 3:**
Running `ldd` on the program in Ubuntu produces `not a dynamic executable` (I guess becaues it's not built for Ubuntu). So I tried [`readelf -d DisplayImage | grep NEEDED`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055340/900394) and I got:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_highgui.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.3.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
```

I found all of them on my target except `ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

Sorry for the long post...

Comment: do not copy libs to your target path, add following command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_of_lib:/another_path_if_there` and the run your exe

Comment: What do you mean? The libs must be present on the target (a different machine)

Comment: Opps, it's cross compilation. Copying is ok.... check your exe with `ldd exe` see if there is any so not found

Comment: That gives `not a dynamic executable`. What does this mean?

Comment: it should be your exe name like `ldd ./DisplayImage`

Comment: I know... That's what I did. It gives `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75054/ldd-tells-me-my-app-is-not-a-dynamic-executable

Comment: @MD.NazmulKibria Please see **edit 3**